# windows phone and local server (tomcat)

Tags: windows-phone-7, tomcat, localhost, localserver

I have running my tomcat server on localhost:6060 
I have created a webRequest from windows phone, but when I run it, exception with no exception-text is unhandled. (Really, just no text in exception) (and there is no response text also)

So I guess, windows phone tries to go in its local ip but there is nothing of course.

I have tried to use "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" but nothing works... and I didn't find the solution for tomcat, only some remarks about IIS.

So, how to redirect windows phone from using its own internal IP? Or what it can be..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the external (LAN) IP-address of your tomcat server. Connecting to `localhost` from your phone won't do any good. Use `ipconfig` or whatever command appropriate for the OS your using to find the external (LAN) IP address, and then use that instead of `localhost` in your `WebRequest`.